# Subfigure arrangement with five images

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am trying to display five images as sub figures, but I would like to arrange them in a different way than what I am currently getting as output. Depending on whether I use the \hfill each *subfloat*, I can get a different arrangement, but I can't seem to be able to arrange them like this (which is what I would like to do):

(a)    (b)    (c)

(d)     (e)

The code and output that I am getting are:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \caption{capt}
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{blank.png}}\hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{blank.png}}\hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{blank.png}}\hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{blank.png}}\hfill
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{blank.png}}   
     \label{lab}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Output example]

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make two paragraphs and use `\centering`. Don't forget the `p` option.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering

\caption{capt}\label{lab}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}}%
\hspace*{0.005\textwidth}%
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.33\textwidth]{example-image}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The separation space in the bottom row will be the same as in the top one.

[image]

Comment: \ in the documentclass

Comment: @jsbibra Thanks: copy/paste error.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you, @egreg

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

Note the blank line and `\medskip` directive after the 3rd of 5 subfigures

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subfig,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\caption{capt}\label{lab}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{dados/figuras/blank.png}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{dados/figuras/blank.png}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{dados/figuras/blank.png}}
    
\medskip
\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{dados/figuras/blank.png}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{dados/figuras/blank.png}}   
\hfill\mbox{}
     
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```